# Use proxy for http request in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy, http-proxy

For debugging purposes, I need to configure Java to use a proxy for HTTP requests. I am wondering how to do it in my Eclipse environment when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>? Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to pass these flags in your run configuration. Run -> Run configurations -> Select your project. Then in second tab: “Arguments”. Top box is for your program's arguments, and bottom box is for VM arguments. Add these two there as VM arguments.

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyserver.com  
-Dhttp.proxyPort=80
```

You can also set them in your code.

```
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "proxyserver.com");
System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
```

You can read more about them in java docs [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html).

Comment: It is arguments or environment?

Comment: @user496949 - Funny. My last three answers here had been to your questions. Strange coincidence indeed.

Comment: Is it program's aruguments or VM arguments?

Answer (score 1):

If its still not working add these also as VM variables in run config.

-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxyserver.com
-Dhttps.proxyPort=80